# HBase: how to unit test HBase Map/Reduce

Tags: unit-testing, hbase

I want to unit test HBase reducer which I wrote in Java and my question is what is the best way to do it (best way = easy and fast)?
I found 'MRUnit' but it is not supporting 'MultipleOutputs' so I look for something that will support it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MRUnit is for MapReduce.
Some Mock tools can help you simulate HBase objects, like nosqlunit, Mockito

Answer (score 0):

W.P.McNeill has a great article where he uses the adapter pattern to circumvent the map reduce framework providing a good unit test tool. That might be a good place to start.

http://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/unit-testing-mapreduce-with-overridden-write-methods/

Comment: I already read this article but I could not found way to implement his solution because I am using  MultipleOutputs.